# React - filter deletes all items instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fail to understand why .filter deletes all items instead of one even though the key should be unique. Why? I think it should filter out the id that is in the function, but it keeps deleting everything, because of the .map, right?

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("")
  const [list, updateList] = useState([])

  const addItem = () => {
    list.push(state)
    setState('')
    updateList(list)
  }

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    updateList(list.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <input placeholder='type...' value={state} onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Submit</button>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <>
            <div key={item.id}>{item}</div>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}>delete</button>
            </>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Your `list` items are just strings they wont have an `id` property, so your filter is testing `undefined !== undefined`

Comment: so how to add it?

Comment: ``list.push({state: state, id: id})``

Comment: You're also mutating state in this line `list.push(state)` rather `updateList(list => [...list, {state, id: 'someuniqueid'}])`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `item.id` actually, you just have item which is a string.
You add items to that array from the text box, so you only have `Array of strings`

What you should do is remove by `item` not `item.id`

your code should be something like that
remoteItem function :

```
const removeItem = (selectedItem) => {
updateList(list.filter((item) => item !== selectedItem));
```

};

Then in your `list.map`

```
{list.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div key={item}>{item}</div>
          <button onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>delete</button>
        </>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("")
  const [list, updateList] = useState([])

  const addItem = () => {
    // list.push(state) // Never change a state like this...!!!
    setState('')
    updateList(old=>[...old, state]) // Modified
  }

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    updateList(old=>old.filter((item) => item.id !== id));  // Modified
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <input placeholder='type...' value={state} onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Submit</button>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <>
            <div key={item.id}>{item}</div>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}>delete</button>
            </>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score -1):

I think in your code the filter method dose not have any return so replace it with this line of code :

```
updateList(list.filter((item) => return item.id !== id));
```